# JavaScript for loop not changing link text

Tags: javascript, css

I have a nested for loop inside a for loop that is supposed to change the link text to a random number between 1 and 5. The ID of the links are "aX_Y", X and Y being numbers.  The links are arranged in a 4x3 square. The problem is that the random numbers for the link text is only displayed for the last row:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RISK</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a:link, a:visited {color: #eee;border:3px solid #ccc;text-decoration:none;padding:20px;}
    .one {background: #7B3B3B;}
    .two {background: #547980;}
    #status {color: #eee;padding:1px;text-align:center}
    .current {border:3px solid #000;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var xTurn = true;
var gameOver = false;
var numMoves = 0;

function newgame()
{
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    numMoves = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    xTurn = true;
    status.innerHTML = 'Player One\'s turn';

    for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            document.getElementById('a' + x + '_' + y).innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);
            console.log('a' + x + '_' + y);
        }
    }
}
function current(selected)
{
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var value = selected.value; 
}
//document.getElementById("status").setAttribute("class", "two");
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
</head>

<body onload='newgame();'>
<p id="status" class="one">Player One's turn</p>
<br />
<a href="#" id="a0_0" class="one current" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_0" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_0" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_0" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br />

<a href="#" id="a0_1" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_1" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_1" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_1" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br />

<a href="#" id="a0_2" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_2" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_2" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_2" class="two" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br /><br />

<p><input type="button" id="newgame" value="New Game" onclick="newgame();" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a direct link to it:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/750932/iPhone/risk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change to your CSS fixes the issue:

```
a:link, a:visited 
{
    color: #eee;
    border:3px solid #ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I'm pretty sure it *is* working...the other boxes are just overlapped by the ones in front and you can't see them. Firebug shows values inside all the boxes.

```
a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

br {
    clear:both;
}
```

...though actually those top-level elements shouldn't be restyled like that necessarily, I'd put it all in a `<div id="game"></div>` and make them `.game a` and `.game br`.

Answer (score 0):

(Tested in Firefox)

Your Javascript code is fine; all of the grid squares are getting populated with random numbers.  What I am seeing instead is that each row of links is overlapping the previous row, so the numbers in the previous row are being hidden.

Is the overlapping intentional?

Answer (score 0):

All the random numbers are being generated correctly. The top 2 rows are just hidden due to your CSS rules. You can prove this by making the following CSS change:

Change the line that looks like this:

```
a:link, a:visited {color: #eee;border:3px solid #ccc;text-decoration:none;padding:20px;}
```

to this:

```
a:link, a:visited {color: #eee;border:3px solid #ccc;text-decoration:none;}
```

And voila, it's all working beautifully.